# Grammar in prolog

Tags: prolog, grammar

I want to be able to translate arrays like `[int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(N)]`into conditions (in this example `[int(2) < int(1)-id(N)]` ) using grammar. I have the grammar below:

```
cond(_, A > B) --> expr(_,A), [sep(>)], expr(_,B).
cond(_, A < B) --> expr(_,A), [sep(<)], expr(_,B).
expr(_, int(X)) --> [int(X)].
expr(_, id(X)) --> [id(X)].
expr(_, X + Y) --> expr(_,X), [sep(+)], expr(_,Y).
expr(_, X - Y) --> expr(_,X), [sep(-)], expr(_,Y).
```

What I don't understand is the fact that if I have the array: `[int(2), sep(>), int(1), sep(+), id(N)]` everything is fine, the condition is translated correctly. I make some changes then, replacing `+` by `-` or `>` by `<` (take account of the fact that in my grammar `>` is one line over `<`, same as `+` and `-`) and this isn't translated, it falls into infinite loop:

```
Call:  (18)  ? [sep(-), id(N)]=[sep(+)|_G2290032]creep
Fail:  (18)  ? [sep(-), id(N)]=[sep(+)|_G2290032]creep
```

It is always comparing to line with `sep(+)`. What is wrong in this grammar?

--EDIT added tracing

```
phrase(cond(_, X), [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-),id(N)]).
   Call:  (10)  ? cond(_G2313, _G2314, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], [])creep
   Call:  (11)  ? expr(_L254, _G2482, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L235)creep
   Exit:  (11)  ? expr(_L254, int(2), [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)])creep
   Call:  (11)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(>)|_G2488]creep
   Fail:  (11)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(>)|_G2488]creep
   Redo:  (11)  ? expr(_L254, _G2482, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L235)creep
   Call:  (12)  ? expr(_L279, _G2485, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L260)creep
   Exit:  (12)  ? expr(_L279, int(2), [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)])creep
   Call:  (12)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2491]creep
   Fail:  (12)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2491]creep
   Redo:  (12)  ? expr(_L279, _G2485, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L260)creep
   Call:  (13)  ? expr(_L304, _G2488, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L285)creep
   Exit:  (13)  ? expr(_L304, int(2), [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)])creep
   Call:  (13)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2494]creep
   Fail:  (13)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2494]creep
   Redo:  (13)  ? expr(_L304, _G2488, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L285)creep
   Call:  (14)  ? expr(_L329, _G2491, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L310)creep
   Exit:  (14)  ? expr(_L329, int(2), [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)])creep
   Call:  (14)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2497]creep
   Fail:  (14)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2497]creep
   Redo:  (14)  ? expr(_L329, _G2491, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L310)creep
   Call:  (15)  ? expr(_L354, _G2494, [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], _L335)creep
   Exit:  (15)  ? expr(_L354, int(2), [int(2), sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)], [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)])creep
   Call:  (15)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2500]creep
   Fail:  (15)  ? [sep(<), int(1), sep(-), id(_G2336)]=[sep(+)|_G2500]
   ...
```

Comment: It could be the left recursion in `expr/2`. If you post complete code that can be just copied and run it is easier to find the problem.

Comment: @TomasBy just added tracing

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TomasBy, left recursion in non terminal expr//2 leads to non termination. In SWI-Prolog there is library([tabling](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling)), just import it and declare expr//2 as tabled.

```
:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table expr//2.
```